# php -S localhost:port: Says waiting for localhost forever

Tags: php

I have `LAMP` installed.

I have `phptest.php` which contains `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

I tried:

```
[.public_html]$ php -S localhost:54545 phptest.php 
[Mon Jan 25 21:06:52 2016] PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.14 Development Server started at Mon Jan 25 21:06:52 2016
Listening on http://localhost:54545
Document root is /home/simha/.public_html
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Then I open `http://localhost:54545` in Chrome and it says `waiting for localhost`.

I tried `http://localhost:81` (why 81 see below) and `http://localhost:81/~simha` all of them works. It shows the respective root directories. There looks no problem with my Apache.

Also some background about the `host` and `container`:

I have Linux OS with LAMP installed. Using `systemd-nspawn` I run the same Linux OS with LAMP in a container.

I have set 80 port for the hosts LAMP and 81 port for the containers LAMP

In the host system there is no such problem. The same file will open in chromium after `php -S localhost:xxxxx phptest.php`

But in the container, it just says `waiting for localhost`.

Comment: I would start with executing the PHP webserver without any script, just `php -S localhost:54545` and then requesting any static (i.e. non-PHP) file. If it works, problem is the most probably in your PHP script `phptest.php`.

Comment: i have added the contents of phptest.php

Comment: And? Does it work for the static files?

Comment: what does static mean

Comment: As I wrote: any static (i.e. **non-PHP**) file. Anything which is not processed by the web server (CSS, JS, images, any other data).

Comment: See my edited question. you want me to try `php -S localhost:1212 1.html`

Comment: No, that doesn't make a sense. Simply `php -S localhost:12345` and request some static file from the document root. But as you clarified your question - you wrote you had a problem with the PHP web server running in a container, so I would say you have to set up the port redirection from your machine, where you're running the client, to the container.

Comment: What container are you using?

Comment: BTW I'm almost sure, that if you request `http://localhost` from your host machine, it's handled by the Apache **on the host**, not inside the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101608/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-dawid-ferenczy).

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** I should have been more clear as to having both web servers (Apache and PHP -S) running on the same port blocking the connection, and not the script being accessed.

You don't need to run `php -S` if you already have LAMP setup. You might have both web servers trying to access the same script, but only one of them can do it, the other is getting blocked:

[Built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: I have another pc with lamp started . The php -S works there without waiting for localhost

Comment: You just misunderstood it. It means, that the built-in web server can handle only one request at the same time. If the request is blocked (didn't end) for some reason, any other request won't be processed. It definitely doesn't mean that you can't have  more different web servers serving the same files. Why or how would be the script blocked for reading?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy But wouldn't it still block if he has his LAMP server configured to listen on the same port as the php built-in server? How would both serve the same script at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can't bind two processed to the same port. But I don't think LAMP (i.e. Apache) is bound to the port 54545 he's using (`php -S localhost:54545`) by default. Anyway, it has nothing to do with any file. Why should the file which is read be blocked for reading?

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Sorry, but your question (even edited) has nothing to do with this answer or these comments.

Comment: Two processes on the same port wouldn't block any connection because it's simply not possible to bind two processes to the same port. Second try to use the same port for another process would fail.

Comment: Then I don't know. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: It's most likely caused by the container (which even haven't been mentioned in the original question).

Answer (score 0):

Virtual ports of your container are not anyhow connected to the physical ports of your host machine by default. That's why you can't access the PHP web server running inside the container. You need to **bind the physical port on your host to the virtual port of your container** first.

Check the [man page for systemd-nspawn](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html) and look for the `--port` option.

It's in this format:

```
--port=<protocol>:<host_port>:<container_port>
```

So it could look like this:

```
systemd-nspawn -bD /home/Mycontainer --port=tcp:80:54545
```

It redirects TCP on port 80 on your host to the port 54545 on the container. If the port 80 on your host is already bound (most probably to the Apache), use another port.

Comment: what parameters i should use with --port. I am running `systemd-nspawn -bD /home/Mycontainer`

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue, I don't know the `nspawn` at all, I just googled everything for you. You have to test it yourself, I can't even try it. Simply redirect the TCP port you're using for the PHP web server inside the container.

Comment: I have added an example, how it should be called.

Comment: No. i tried `--port tcp:80:545454` i got the `Failed to parse host port tcp:80:545454: Invalid argument` . More than that i want to avoid port forwarding. Because localhost:54545/1.html works, while localhost:54545/phptest.php is not working. Is there a way to see some log files when i connect.

Comment: BTW it should be `--port=` (you're missing equals. And you can omit the protocol, so it could look like `--port=80:54545`, but don't use 80, if it's already used on your host. But if it works for the static files, port forwarding doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: Yes. it is working for static files. port forwarding is not the problem. Some problem with the php of the container. Because the hosts php works fine. Also its not problem of apache. Both the localhost of host and localhost:81 of container show all the files.